# Add a prefix to URL patterns

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

I have a Django application that has several entries in URL patterns (`urls.py`):

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    # change Language
    (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url('^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-docs/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/api/v1/')),
    url(r'^api/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/api/v1/')),
    url(r'^api/v1', RedirectView.as_view(url='/api/v1/')),

    # django default stuff
    url(r'^accounts/', include('main.registration_urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # oath2_provider
    url(r'^o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),

    # google urls
    url(r'^gauthtest/$',
        'main.google_export.google_oauth2_request',
        name='google-auth'),
    url(r'^gwelcome/$',
        'main.google_export.google_auth_return',
        name='google-auth-welcome'),

    # main website views
    url(r'^$', 'main.views.home'),
    url(r'^tutorial/$', 'main.views.tutorial', name='tutorial'),
    url(r'^about-us/$', 'main.views.about_us', name='about-us'),
    url(r'^getting_started/$', 'main.views.getting_started', name='getting_started'),
    url(r'^faq/$', 'main.views.faq', name='faq'),
    url(r'^syntax/$', 'main.views.syntax', name='syntax'),
    url(r'^resources/$', 'main.views.resources', name='resources'),
    url(r'^forms/$', 'main.views.form_gallery', name='forms_list'),
    url(r'^forms/(?P<uuid>[^/]+)$', 'main.views.show'),
    url(r'^people/$', 'main.views.members_list'),
    url(r'^xls2xform/$', 'main.views.xls2xform'),
    url(r'^support/$', 'main.views.support'),
    url(r'^stats/$', 'staff.views.stats'),
    url(r'^login_redirect/$', 'main.views.login_redirect'),
    url(r"^attachment/$", 'odk_viewer.views.attachment_url'),
    url(r"^attachment/(?P<size>[^/]+)$", 'odk_viewer.views.attachment_url'),
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog',
        {'packages': ('main', 'odk_viewer',)}),
    url(r'^typeahead_usernames', 'main.views.username_list', name='username_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/$', 'main.views.profile', name='user_profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/profile$', 'main.views.public_profile', name='public_profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/settings', 'main.views.profile_settings'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/cloneform$', 'main.views.clone_xlsform'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/activity$', 'main.views.activity'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/activity/api$', 'main.views.activity_api'),
    url(r'^activity/fields$', 'main.views.activity_fields'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/api-token$', 'main.views.api_token'),

    # form specific
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)$', 'main.views.show'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/qrcode$', 'main.views.qrcode', name='get_qrcode'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/api$', 'main.views.api', name='mongo_view_api'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/public_api$', 'main.views.public_api', name='public_api'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/delete_data$', 'main.views.delete_data', name='delete_data'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/edit$', 'main.views.edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/perms$', 'main.views.set_perm'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/bamboo$', 'main.views.link_to_bamboo'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/photos', 'main.views.form_photos'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/doc/(?P<data_id>\d+)', 'main.views.download_metadata'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/delete-doc/(?P<data_id>\d+)', 'main.views.delete_metadata'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/formid-media/(?P<data_id>\d+)', 'main.views.download_media_data'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/submission/(?P<uuid>[^/]+)$', 'main.views.show_submission'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/addservice$', 'restservice.views.add_service', name="add_restservice"),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/delservice$',
        'restservice.views.delete_service', name="delete_restservice"),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/update$', 'main.views.update_xform'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/preview$', 'main.views.enketo_preview'),

    # briefcase api urls
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/view/submissionList$",
        'odk_logger.views.view_submission_list'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/view/downloadSubmission$",
        'odk_logger.views.view_download_submission'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/formUpload$",
        'odk_logger.views.form_upload'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/upload$",
        'odk_logger.views.form_upload'),

    # stats
    url(r"^stats/submissions/$", 'staff.views.submissions'),

    # exporting stuff
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/data\.csv$", 'odk_viewer.views.data_export', name='csv_export', kwargs={'export_type': 'csv'}),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/data\.xls", 'odk_viewer.views.data_export', name='xls_export', kwargs={'export_type': 'xls'}),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/data\.csv.zip", 'odk_viewer.views.data_export', name='csv_zip_export', kwargs={'export_type': 'csv_zip'}),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/data\.kml$", 'odk_viewer.views.kml_export'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/data\.zip", 'odk_viewer.views.zip_export'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/gdocs$", 'odk_viewer.views.google_xls_export'),
    url(r"^odk_viewer/survey/(?P<instance_id>\d+)/$", 'odk_viewer.views.survey_responses'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/map_embed", 'odk_viewer.views.map_embed_view'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/map", 'odk_viewer.views.map_view'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/instance", 'odk_viewer.views.instance'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/enter-data", 'odk_logger.views.enter_data', name='enter_data'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/add-submission-with", 'odk_viewer.views.add_submission_with', name='add_submission_with'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/thank_you_submission", 'odk_viewer.views.thank_you_submission', name='thank_you_submission'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/edit-data/(?P<data_id>\d+)$", 'odk_logger.views.edit_data', name='edit_data'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/view-data", 'odk_viewer.views.data_view'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/exports/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/(?P<export_type>\w+)/new$", 'odk_viewer.views.create_export'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/exports/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/(?P<export_type>\w+)/delete$", 'odk_viewer.views.delete_export'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/exports/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/(?P<export_type>\w+)/progress$", 'odk_viewer.views.export_progress'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/exports/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/(?P<export_type>\w+)/$", 'odk_viewer.views.export_list'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/exports/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/(?P<export_type>\w+)/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$", 'odk_viewer.views.export_download'),

    # odk data urls
    url(r"^submission$", 'odk_logger.views.submission'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/formList$", 'odk_logger.views.formList'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/xformsManifest/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)$",
        'odk_logger.views.xformsManifest'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/submission$", 'odk_logger.views.submission'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/bulk-submission$", 'odk_logger.views.bulksubmission'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/bulk-submission-form$", 'odk_logger.views.bulksubmission_form'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/form\.xml$", 'odk_logger.views.download_xform', name="download_xform"),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/form\.xls$", 'odk_logger.views.download_xlsform', name="download_xlsform"),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/form\.json", 'odk_logger.views.download_jsonform', name="download_jsonform"),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/delete/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/$", 'odk_logger.views.delete_xform'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/toggle_downloadable/$", 'odk_logger.views.toggle_downloadable'),

    # SMS support
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/sms_submission/(?P<service>[a-z]+)/?$', 'sms_support.providers.import_submission_for_form', name='sms_submission_form_api'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/sms_submission$', 'sms_support.views.import_submission_for_form', name='sms_submission_form'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>[^/]+)/sms_submission/(?P<service>[a-z]+)/?$", 'sms_support.providers.import_submission', name='sms_submission_api'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/sms_multiple_submissions$', 'sms_support.views.import_multiple_submissions_for_form', name='sms_submissions_form'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>[^/]+)/sms_multiple_submissions$", 'sms_support.views.import_multiple_submissions', name='sms_submissions'),
    url(r"^(?P<username>[^/]+)/sms_submission$", 'sms_support.views.import_submission', name='sms_submission'),

    # static media
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^favicon\.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/images/favicon.ico'))
)
```

I need to add a prefix to each URL (e.g., `/myprefix/` ) but instead of adding the prefix to each of entry manually (editing each line) Is it possible to add the prefix through Python code?

Answer (score 18):

Make a pattern that looks for the common URL prefix, then include a second patterns object:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^myprefix/', include(patterns(
        '',
        # change Language
       (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
       url('^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
       url(r'^api-docs/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/api/v1/')),
       url(r'^api/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/api/v1/')),
       url(r'^api/v1', RedirectView.as_view(url='/api/v1/')),
       # Et cetera
    )
)
```

In fact you should perhaps group all the URLs that start with `api/` this way, and definitely all the ones that start with `r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/forms/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/'`.

Edit: I didn't test that, see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) under "Including other URLconfs".

Comment: Hi, I tried you code with prefix = formhub but I get Page not found (404):  

Using the URLconf defined in formhub.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^formhub/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

Comment: I wrote that without testing it, after having found the docs. Now at home, see the link I edited in.

Answer (score 12):

For django 2+ it is now

```py
from django.conf.urls import include
.
.
.
urlpatterns = [
... # Your URL patterns
]
# Add 'prefix' to all urlpatterns
urlpatterns = [path(r'^prefix/', include(urlpatterns))]
```

I am using this with a setting so that I can deploy to different environments easily this is how I am doing that.

```py
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf import settings
.
.
urlpatterns = [
... # Your URL patterns
]
# Add 'prefix' to all urlpatterns
if settings.URL_PREFIX:
    urlpatterns = [path(f'{settings.URL_PREFIX}/', include(urlpatterns))]
```

URL_PREFIX has to be designated in the settings as well.

Comment: That works perfectly. But do you use internationalization ? It keeps producing errors. Also the cases where it works would produce a pattern where I have `/fr/URL_PREFIX/` while I want `/URL_PREFIX/fr/`.

Comment: I don't but you might be able to get the same result by wrapping URL prefix path with `i18n_patterns`  here is the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns

Comment: Whenever I apply internarlization on the first `urlpatterns` and use that in an `urlpatterns = [path(f'{settings.URL_PREFIX}/', include(urlpatterns))]`, it produces an error saying that `Using i18n_patterns in an included URLconf is not allowed.` And that is what I want. Prefix to come before the language indication thing like `/cute_prefix/fr/`

Comment: @iMitwe have you finally found à way to prefix it? I need the same for my app like `app/fr/connexion`

Comment: Note yet. I haven't found a proper way of doing this. @CallMarl

Answer (score 10):

Simply create an django app and move all your current code into that app. And finally include this urls.py into your project's urls.py. like this

```
url(r'^myprefix/', include('app.urls')),
```

Answer (score 10):

I found out in Django docs there is a use case for URL prefix.

In Django docs: [Including other URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs):

> We can improve this by stating the common path prefix only once and grouping the suffixes that differ:
>
> ```
> from django.conf.urls import include, url
> from . import views
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     url(r'^(?P<page_slug>[\w-]+)-(?P<page_id>\w+)/', include([
>         url(r'^history/$', views.history),
>         url(r'^edit/$', views.edit),
>         url(r'^discuss/$', views.discuss),
>         url(r'^permissions/$', views.permissions),
>     ])),
> ]
> ```

Comment: Work for Django 1.9 as well. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

If you want just add a prefix for all URLs you can use the following code in *urls.py* file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
.
.
.
urlpatterns = [
... # Your URL patterns
]
# Add 'prefix' to all urlpatterns
urlpatterns = [url(r'^prefix/', include(urlpatterns))]
```

It'll add prefix for all *urlpatterns*.