# Serving two Django apps with Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django app running with Nginx and Gunicorn on ***mysite.com***. I would like to deploy a second Django app to be reachable under ***mysite.com/secondapp*** while my first app still just by ***mysite.com***.

I followed the tutorial from DigitalOcean and my current config for App 1 is:

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myproject.wsgi:application
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

My question is: do I need to create 2 separate **.socket** and **.service** file for my App 2 and how do I make App 2 accessible by *mysite.com/secondapp* ?

Comment: In addition to the answer given by @mgsxman, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997863/add-a-prefix-to-url-patterns-in-django) Q/A.

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks exactly like what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to create 2 separate `.socket` and `.service` files.

Then your Nginx config will look like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir;
    }
    location = /secondapp/static/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir-app2;
    }


    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    location /secondapp/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn-app2.sock:/;
    }
}
```

Note that you have to configure your second app to search for static at correct location.

**Update:**

All routes on second app should also be changed from `/route_path/` to `/secondapp/route_path/`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Before creating .socket and .service for the second app, I decided to try to add location /firstapp/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    } to test if its working. For some reason I get "Not Found.The requested URL /firstapp/ was not found on this server." Nginx error log doesnt show anything usefull.

Comment: Note the trailing `:/` at  `proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn-app2.sock:/;`  Because socket root is `/` at which it accept connections.

Comment: See update, try to change routes at second app, and leave `proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn-app2.sock;`

Comment: That worked great, without ":/" in the end. Could you please explain me why we didn't need to create a separate entry in "sites-available" for the app2, but append it to to app1 config?

Comment: Because you can not use the same `server_name server_domain;` in two different configs. But that will be possible if you are able to use another domain name, like `server_name server_domain-app2;`